# Can I install ipa from my app or web just like testflight?

Tags: ios, ipa, testflight

I am very interesting with testflight, it make possible to do test before app is ready for publish. But testflight is very slow at my country. I really like implement my own testflight.

Some app can install ipa, when you press install it will popup a dialog ask you "if you want to install xxx from 127.0.0.1"

Recently, I read an article, a team has develop a system, which can install daily build version of app. You can see the image below. "iOS版" is "iOS version", "安卓版" is "Android version", "安装" is "install"。

[image]
<sub>(source: [gameres.com](http://www.gameres.com/data/attachment/forum/201312/06/2145147aebfabiaefx7xm7.jpg))</sub>

The android version is easy, but the iOS version is very hard. How can I install an ipa from an app or web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could have a look at this apple doucment:[Installing apps wirelessly](https://help.apple.com/iosdeployment-apps/mac/1.1/?lang=en-us#app43ad871e)

With this doucment,you could creat a ad-hoc ipa,and upload to your server, people coule install the ipa via safari.

(Btw:其实你可以看这篇[文章](http://www.iinterest.net/2011/09/22/installing-apps-wirelessly-ipa-ota/)，里面有一个demo的链接，虽然这个demo上面的ipa需要越狱才能安装，仅仅是给你看一下效果。如果你有加入udid或者用企业证书打包，那就没有限制了，无需越狱)